# Google API file permissions

Tags: php, linux, permissions, google-api

If I run the Google_CustomsearchService API in alternately from two different users on Ubuntu linux, I get permission problems (cannot create directory or cannot create or write file) on temporary files the API creates in /tmp/Google_Client.  This is true even if both users are in the same group.  This is true even if the users are in the same group.  The crux of the problem is that the directores are being created 755 and the files are being created 644.  This is true, even though I have put umask 002 in my .profile, and the system umask is set to 002.  There must be something somewhere in the Google API overriding this.  So I have one search with is initiated from a web browser.  This search creates files under the user www-data (which comes from the Apache installation).  If I run the search from the command line, it runs under my personal userid.  Since my user id is not www-data, it throws an uncaught exception in the Google API because I cannot write to files or directories created by www-data or visa versa.  Has anyone run into this problem, and does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to set up Google and Ubuntu to allow me to run the Google custom search client from multiple users, so I created a workaround. :)  I set up a web page under apache that calls each of the search scripts I wanted to run.  Any user must use the web page to run the script.  That way all searches run under the www-data user id.  I just have to be careful not to try to run the custom search client any other way (from the command line).